# Simplest and Sure manner adding multiple Groups and Users, CentOS 7, macOS

Tags: bash, unix, user-account, group

I have this instructions on **CentOS 7** Linux version.

```
$ sudo groupadd oinstall
$ sudo groupadd dba
$ sudo groupadd oper

$ sudo useradd -G dba,oper -g oinstall oracle
$ sudo passwd oracle
```

And Already I know that it is possible to add group and user using:

```
$ sudo dscl . -create /Groups/nameGroup

$ sudo dscl . -create /Groups/nameGroup PrimaryGroupID xNumberGroup
$ sudo dscl . -create /Groups/nameGroup RealName "nameGroup Daemon Group"
$ sudo dscl . -create /Groups/nameGroup passwd "*"

$ sudo dscl . -create /Users/nameUser UniqueID xNumberUser
$ sudo dscl . -create /Users/nameUser PrimaryGroupID xNumberGroup
$ sudo dscl . -create /Users/nameUser UserShell /usr/bin/false
$ sudo dscl . -create /Users/nameUser RealName "nameUser Daemon User"
$ sudo dscl . -create /Users/nameUser passwd "*"
$ sudo dscl . -create /Users/nameUser NFSHomeDirectory: /usr/local/Some/Folder

$ sudo dscl .  append Groups/nameGroup GroupMembership nameUser
```

The question is *how to perform Linux steps on macOS in the **simplest** and **sure** manner?*

When I say the above I want to imply, what lines can I do without?

PD: I know is it possible install Oracle Database using Virtual Machine but I'm not interested (I'm exploring this way).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add a group account on macOS is to use **System Preferences/Accounts**, click the <kbd>+</kbd> button and select the type of account to **Group**

[image: create group in system preferences]

However, if you are looking for a simple way to add a group account in command line then other than the **dscl** option there is also the Directory Service command line tools. Type following in Terminal:

```
dseditgroup -o create -u myadminuser -P myadminpassword -r "Some Group" somegroup
```

That will create the group account in the /Local/Default domain (same as the above in GUI).

You can add an existing user to the newly added group with:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -u myadminuser -P myadminpassword -t user -a someuser somegroup
```

and check membership in the group with:

```
dseditgroup -o checkmember -m someuser somegroup
```

It will display either:

```
yes someuser is a member of somegroup
```

or

```
no someuser is NOT a member of somegroup
```